# Prove that there is no $k$ such that $a_n$ is positive for all $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am practicing for my calculus final exam and I found this problem that I dont know where to start! I wonder if any convergence tests might help but I dont find the way through:

Prove that $$\nexists k\in\mathbb{R}:a_{n}>0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ given the sequence $$\begin{cases}
a_{1}= & k\\
a_{n}= & \frac{n}{n-1}a_{n-1}-1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hint: Write $b_{n} = a_{n}/n$. How does $b_{n}$ behave?

Answer (score 0):

Parital answer here.

Assuming that $a_n$ is bounded from above by a real number $M$, the proof seems rather simple.

The value of $a_n$ changes, in the next step, to the value $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{n}a_n-1 = a_n + \frac1n a_n - 1$,

meaning that for large values of $n$, $a_n$ you have $$a_{n+1} + \frac1n a_n - 1 < a_n + \frac Mn - 1$$

so if $n$ is large enough, for example so large that $\frac Mn < \frac12$, you know that $a_{n+1}$ is smaller by at least $\frac12$ compared to $a_n$, meaning it will, eventually, fall below $0$.

I believe that it should not be too hard to show that $a_n$ is bounded, but I didn't make it yet...